# Python распарсить список значений по названию списка, и по номеру значения в списке

Tags: python

```
data = {'lastUpdateId': 490726351, 
'bids': [['0.57860000', '518.00000000'], ['0.57850000', '643.00000000'], ['0.57840000', '518.00000000'], ['0.57830000', '407.00000000'], ['0.57820000', '446.00000000'], ['0.57810000', '419.00000000'], ['0.57790000', '68.00000000'], ['0.57780000', '1206.00000000'], ['0.57770000',
'4199.00000000'], ['0.57750000', '2791.00000000'], ['0.57730000', '267.00000000'], ['0.57720000', '5000.00000000'], ['0.57710000', '303.00000000'], ['0.57700000', '274.00000000'], ['0.57680000', '990.00000000'], ['0.57670000', '683.00000000'], ['0.57660000', '27.00000000'], ['0.57640000', '684.00000000'], ['0.57630000', '567.00000000'], ['0.57600000', '361.00000000'], ['0.57590000', '301.00000000'], ['0.57550000', '256.00000000'], ['0.57540000', '2980.00000000'], ['0.57500000', '2559.00000000'], ['0.57470000', '1836.00000000'], ['0.57440000', '1389.00000000'], ['0.57430000', '480.00000000'], ['0.57400000', '22.00000000'], ['0.57360000', '870.00000000'], ['0.57350000', '1190.00000000'], ['0.57340000', '48.00000000'], ['0.57330000', '648.00000000'], ['0.57290000', '1865.00000000'], ['0.57270000', '502.00000000'], ['0.57260000', '3601.00000000'], ['0.57230000', '873.00000000'], ['0.57190000', '141.00000000'], ['0.57180000', '583.00000000'], ['0.57160000', '1317.00000000'], ['0.57140000', '143.00000000'], ['0.57090000', '464.00000000'], ['0.57070000', '1204.00000000'], ['0.57060000', '48.00000000'], ['0.57040000', '518.00000000'], ['0.57030000', '1317.00000000'], ['0.57010000', '17447.00000000'], ['0.57000000', '9516.00000000'], ['0.56980000', '820.00000000'], ['0.56970000', '912.00000000'], ['0.56940000', '35.00000000'], ['0.56930000', '3582.00000000'], ['0.56920000', '1103.00000000'], ['0.56900000', '1142.00000000'], ['0.56810000', '637.00000000'], ['0.56800000', '100.00000000'], ['0.56770000', '3024.00000000'], ['0.56710000', '312.00000000'], ['0.56680000', '53.00000000'], ['0.56660000', '422.00000000'], ['0.56650000', '18.00000000'], ['0.56600000', '1202.00000000'], ['0.56560000', '26.00000000'], ['0.56500000', '189.00000000'], ['0.56490000', '100.00000000'], ['0.56470000', '910.00000000'], ['0.56420000', '313.00000000'], ['0.56410000', '89.00000000'], ['0.56400000', '101.00000000'], ['0.56390000', '115.00000000'], ['0.56270000', '551.00000000'], ['0.56210000', '578.00000000'], ['0.56200000', '22.00000000'], ['0.56170000', '25.00000000'], ['0.56130000', '39.00000000'], ['0.56120000', '557.00000000'], ['0.56070000', '2737.00000000'], ['0.56050000', '100.00000000'], ['0.56040000', '136.00000000'], ['0.56030000', '100.00000000'], ['0.56020000', '100.00000000'], ['0.56010000', '100.00000000'], ['0.56000000', '593.00000000'], ['0.55990000', '100.00000000'], ['0.55980000', '100.00000000'], ['0.55970000', '100.00000000'], ['0.55960000', '100.00000000'], ['0.55930000', '49.00000000'], ['0.55920000', '136.00000000'], ['0.55890000', '25.00000000'], ['0.55860000', '1676.00000000'],
['0.55810000', '155.00000000'], ['0.55800000', '994.00000000'], ['0.55710000', '25.00000000'], ['0.55700000', '128.00000000'], ['0.55650000', '299.00000000'], ['0.55590000', '359.00000000'], ['0.55560000', '36.00000000'], ['0.55520000', '180.00000000'], ['0.55510000', '344.00000000'], ['0.55500000', '5456.00000000']], 
'asks': [['0.57920000', '728.00000000'], ['0.57930000', '485.00000000'], ['0.57940000', '904.00000000'], ['0.57950000', '14480.00000000'], ['0.58070000', '6812.00000000'], ['0.58080000', '274.00000000'], ['0.58090000', '298.00000000'], ['0.58120000', '258.00000000'], ['0.58200000', '313.00000000'], ['0.58260000', '934.00000000'], ['0.58280000', '562.00000000'], ['0.58300000', '730.00000000'], ['0.58320000', '47.00000000'], ['0.58340000', '389.00000000'], ['0.58380000', '70.00000000'], ['0.58390000', '1371.00000000'], ['0.58410000', '1190.00000000'], ['0.58460000', '870.00000000'], ['0.58470000', '4345.00000000'], ['0.58500000', '1346.00000000'], ['0.58520000', '680.00000000'], ['0.58530000', '403.00000000'], ['0.58540000', '4559.00000000'], ['0.58570000', '19.00000000'], ['0.58600000', '69.00000000'], ['0.58630000', '1316.00000000'], ['0.58710000', '37.00000000'], ['0.58750000', '1205.00000000'], ['0.58770000', '26.00000000'], ['0.58780000', '20.00000000'], ['0.58830000', '17.00000000'], ['0.58890000', '47.00000000'], ['0.58900000', '2484.00000000'], ['0.58960000', '56.00000000'], ['0.58970000', '1110.00000000'], ['0.59000000', '947.00000000'], ['0.59040000', '27.00000000'], ['0.59070000', '84.00000000'], ['0.59090000', '1825.00000000'], ['0.59100000', '1380.00000000'], ['0.59140000', '2976.00000000'], ['0.59170000', '402.00000000'], ['0.59200000', '46.00000000'], ['0.59300000', '44.00000000'], ['0.59310000', '34.00000000'], ['0.59370000', '21.00000000'], ['0.59400000', '1925.00000000'], ['0.59490000',
'46.00000000'], ['0.59500000', '408.00000000'], ['0.59720000', '3573.00000000'], ['0.59750000', '429.00000000'], ['0.59780000', '46.00000000'], ['0.59800000', '22.00000000'], ['0.59830000', '175.00000000'], ['0.59900000', '200.00000000'], ['0.59980000', '344.00000000'], ['0.60000000', '3827.00000000'], ['0.60080000', '46.00000000'], ['0.60120000', '58.00000000'], ['0.60130000', '1277.00000000'], ['0.60200000', '22.00000000'], ['0.60260000', '39.00000000'], ['0.60270000', '39.00000000'], ['0.60290000', '117.00000000'], ['0.60370000', '95.00000000'], ['0.60380000', '45.00000000'], ['0.60400000', '5456.00000000'], ['0.60470000', '33.00000000'], ['0.60540000', '123.00000000'], ['0.60600000', '22.00000000'], ['0.60610000', '189.00000000'], ['0.60680000', '36.00000000'], ['0.60690000', '45.00000000'], ['0.60750000', '49.00000000'], ['0.60780000', '38.00000000'], ['0.60790000', '55.00000000'], ['0.60840000', '217.00000000'], ['0.60930000', '105.00000000'], ['0.60940000', '38.00000000'], ['0.60990000', '71.00000000'], ['0.61000000', '9841.00000000'], ['0.61170000', '4932.00000000'], ['0.61290000', '45.00000000'], ['0.61330000', '562.00000000'], ['0.61350000', '20.00000000'], ['0.61360000', '54.00000000'], ['0.61400000',
'436.00000000'], ['0.61470000', '40.00000000'], ['0.61500000', '5453.00000000'], ['0.61520000', '41.00000000'], ['0.61550000', '17.00000000'], ['0.61590000', '460.00000000'], ['0.61600000', '3759.00000000'], ['0.61630000', '68.00000000'], ['0.61660000', '33.00000000'], ['0.61690000', '17.00000000'], ['0.61740000', '37.00000000'], ['0.61800000', '831.00000000'], ['0.61810000', '129.00000000'], ['0.61890000', '18.00000000']]}
```

Дано:
Переменная data с заявками на покупку bids и asks.

```
'bids': [['0.57860000', '518.00000000'],
```

где 0.57860000 - цена,
518 - количество

Заявки на продажу

```
'asks': [['0.57860000', '518.00000000'],
```

где 0.57920000 - цена,
728 - количество

Нужно получить значения только из bids или asks

```
bidOrderPrice_1 = 0.57860000
bidOrderQty_1 = 518.00000000
```

или

```
askOrderPrice_1 = 0.57860000
askOrderQty_1 = 518.00000000
```

желательно получать по порядковому номеру, например
указал [0], получил первое значение

```
bidOrderPrice_1 = 0.57860000
bidOrderQty_1 = 518.00000000
```

указал [1], получил второе значение

```
bidOrderPrice_2 = 0.57850000
bidOrderQty_2 = 643.00000000
```

Comment: ну получайте раз нужно получить. Данные упорядочены, значит, задача решается элементарно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные у вас если их нормально отформатировать выглядят примерно так:

```
{'asks': [['0.57920000', '728.00000000'],
          ['0.57930000', '485.00000000'],
          ...
          ['0.61890000', '18.00000000']],
 'bids': [['0.57860000', '518.00000000'],
          ['0.57850000', '643.00000000'],
          ...
          ['0.55500000', '5456.00000000']],
 'lastUpdateId': 490726351}
```

То есть на верхнем уровне - словарь, внутри каждого словаря - список, внутри этого списка - ещё список из двух элементов. Как брать данные?

- из словаря данные берутся по ключу, например `data['asks']`
- из списка данные берутся по индексу, например `list1[0]`
- из списка фиксированной длины данные можно "распаковать" в переменные: `bidOrderPrice_1, bidOrderQty_1 = list2`

Полностью решение писать не буду, хотя его в другом ответе примерно написали.

Answer (score 1):

Воспроизводить ваш словарь не буду, добавите сами. Если в упрощенном варианте, без проверок и прочих манипуляций, то так:

```
data = {'lastUpdateId': 490726351}


def main():
    print(f"Доступно заявок на покупку: {len(data['bids'])}")
    print(f"Доступно заявок на продажу: {len(data['asks'])}\n")

    user_bids = int(input(f'Введите номер заявки на покупку от 1 до {len(data["bids"])}: '))-1
    user_asks = int(input(f'Введите номер заявки на продажу от 1 до {len(data["asks"])}: '))-1

    try:
        print(f'\nПокупка цена: {data["bids"][user_bids][0]}')
        print(f'Покупка количество: {data["bids"][user_bids][1]}\n')

        print(f'Продажа цена: {data["asks"][user_asks][0]}')
        print(f'Продажа количество: {data["asks"][user_asks][1]}')
    except IndexError:
        print('Нет доступных заявок')
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```